# Error in my script using Re library

Tags: python-2.7

In the following sample, i can't get the data with the lib `re` What I'm doing wrong ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import  urllib
import re

def getData():

    res=urllib.urlopen("http://www.quanshuwang.com/book/0/149/34333.html").read()
    html = res.decode("gbk").encode("utf-8")
    reg = r'style5\(\);</script>(.*?)<script type="text/javascript">style6'
    print re.findall(reg,html)

getData()
```

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: I want to get the Chinese between "style5() ;</script>" with   " <script type="text/javascript">style6",but the result is None

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 reg = r'style5\(\);</script>(.*?)<script type="text/javascript">style6'
```

I think your problem is about synthax :

```
reg = 'style5\(\);</script>(.*?)<script type="text/javascript">style6'
```

You have to remove the extra `"r"`

Comment: you still not given the error you got... what is your error ? guessing is not the job of stack overflow users...